# Can't update DNS record on Route 53 using boto3

Tags: python, dns, amazon-route53, boto3

I'm trying to get an dynamic DNS updater script working using AWS Route 53, python3 and boto3. It functions as follows:

1. Retrieve machine IP from an internet service
2. Retrieve current IP in Route 53 DNS
3. Check if they match (if so, exit)
4. Update DNS (replace old IP with current one)

Step 4 is not working. The code for it is below. `my_ip` contains a string that looks like this: `1.2.3.4`. I have tried replacing it with a string directly (`"Value": "1.2.3.4"`) but that didn't fix the error. `hosted_zone_id` is correct as it was already used to pull the IP address. `record_name` is `"microbug.uk."`.

```
response = client.change_resource_record_sets(
    HostedZoneId=hosted_zone_id,
    ChangeBatch={
        "Comment": "Automatic DNS update",
        "Changes": [
            {
                "Action": "UPSERT",
                "ResourceRecordSet": {
                    "Name": record_name,
                    "Type": "A",
                    "Region": "eu-west-1",
                    "TTL": 180,
                    "ResourceRecords": [
                        {
                            "Value": my_ip
                        },
                    ],
                }
            },
        ]
    }
)
```

This is the error it throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "update-dns.py", line 42, in <module>
    "Value": my_ip
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 278, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 572, in _make_api_call
    raise ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidInput) when calling the ChangeResourceRecordSets operation: Invalid request
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

edit:

```
$ cat ~/.aws/config
[default]
region = eu-west-1
output = json
```

Comment: Can you paste the content of this file ~/.aws/config with our credentials and my_ip should be in double or single quotes.

Comment: @error2007s I posted the file. my_ip is a variable set elsewhere in the script, with a string value (e.g., `my_ip="8.8.8.8"`).

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem. The `Region` option must only be set for latency-based record sets; commenting it out solved the problem.